# Creating Content Blocks with Different Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Disclaimer: I'm a PHP developer and am somewhat new to Rails.

I am working on an application which requires me to create blocks of content. There are different types of blocks but they do share common elements (Title, Location). The issue I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around is the fact that each block could have its content defined in a different way.

For example:

Content Block (content) - This block stores html entered in by a user, so it would get its data pulled from a database.

Calendar Block (calendar) - This block displays a listing of events, so it would need to render a view

Integration Block (integration) - This block is an example of a third party integration block. It may get its data by parsing a json feed and rendering it in a particular way.

So my thought was maybe to create each of these block types as a module or plugin that registers a block type and provides info as to how and where to get that data. Similar to how Drupal's hook system works. I'm struggling to figure out a smart way to architect this. There could, in theory be an unlimited amount of block types and I want to make sure I can keep this code base modular and organized.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the strategy pattern:

Assume you get some data from the db such as:

```
block_content_from_db = [
  { block_type: "Content", content: "some html", ...any other attributes... },
  { block_type: "Calendar", content: "appointment data", ...any other attributes... },
  { block_type: "Integration", content: "integration data", ...any other attributes... }
]
```

And you implement each block type and a superclass:

```
class Block
  def initialize(block_data)
    @block_data = block_data
    @renderer = Blocks.const_get "#{block_data[:block_type]}Block"
  end

  def render
    @renderer.new(@block_data).render
  end
end

module Blocks
  class ContentBlock < Block
    def initialize(block_data)
      @block_data = block_data
    end

    def render
      "Rendered ContentBlock: #{@block_data[:content]}"
    end
  end

  class CalendarBlock < Block
    def initialize(block_data)
      @block_data = block_data
    end

    def render
      "Rendered CalendarBlock: #{@block_data[:content]}"
    end
  end

  ... and so on ...
end
```

Then, to render all `block_content_from_db`:

```
block_content_from_db.each do |block_data|
  Block.new(block_data).render
end

# => "Rendered ContentBlock: some html"
# => "Rendered CalendarBlock: appointment data"
```

Now when you want to add an a new block type just subclass from Block again and define a `render` method that accepts `content` from the db to use in rendering. The `content` can be anything that block type needs.

You don't necessarily need to subclass from Block either, just if you want to share common methods between subclasses.

By putting the subclasses in the `Blocks` module we're simply namespacing them so we can later do `Blocks.constants` and get a list of all implemented block renderers and, say, use that in a dropdown menu in the UI for creating new `block_content_from_db`s.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This gets me started down the right path. I appreciate it!